# Angualar 8: predefined values as property in model

Tags: angular, typescript

Let say I'm defining model Person

```
export class Person {
 public firstName: string;
 public lastName: string;
 public gender: ???;
}
```

I want gender to be either 'Male' or 'Female'.

I guess I have to create anther class (in same model or separate??).

```
export class Gender {
 public id: number;
 public name: string;
}
```

and construct values `[{0: "Male"},{1: "Female"}]`

Is this the right way to do it?
If yes how do I define that Gender type in Person model?

Answer (score 2):

First of all in Typescript use interfaces instead of classes for models with only attributes in them. Use classes only when you want a constructor and define methods that do computational work.

There are 3 ways to solve your problem, you can either use an interface in the same you you mentioned, or you can define Gender as an `enum`, or you do this:

```
export interface Person {
 public firstName: string;
 public lastName: string;
 public gender: 'Male' | 'Female';
}
```

Comment: Great. Extended question to it. What if in the future I want to have these values in another languages. I would store them in BE (dictionary) and get from API call. Should I use class or interface then?

Comment: It shouldn't matter because API communication usually happens through strings. The difference between an interface and a class in Typescript is that interfaces don't get transpiled to Javascript, so if you use classes all the time your application will be bigger than if you use interfaces. Classes should be used when you want to do some work when you're initializing your object, e.g. if you want to set a default value or do some calculations or have some methods..etc. But for attributes only, it's better to use interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can either go your class way, then define it like this:

```
export class Person {
 public firstName: string;
 public lastName: string;
 public gender: Gender;
}
```

or, use strings:

```
export class Person {
 public firstName: string;
 public lastName: string;
 public gender: "Male" | "Female";
}
```

That way you do not need another class.

Answer (score 0):

Use `boolean` type

`public gender: boolean;`

If `gender` value is true means male else female. That's it

Comment: transgender will be out of scope then!

Comment: Oh! then we can go with others answer  like : `public gender: 'Male' | 'Female' | 'Other';`

Answer (score 0):

**You could use enum**

```
export enum Gender{
 Male,
 Female,
 Other
}

export class Person {
 public firstName: string;
 public lastName: string;
 public gender: Gender;
}
```

[enum in typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)